# How do I check if a list contains a tuple in C#

Tags: c#, list, tuples

Before adding a new tuple, I want to check if a list already contains that tuple and avoiding adding it to the list again, how would I got about doing this? I'm aware for integers and strings you would just write list.Contains(2) or list.Contains("2"), but i'm not sure what syntax to use when checking for tuples.

I've tried these two so far (snippets). (combination is a list of tuples<char, char>)

```
if(!combinations.Contains(Tuple<char, char>(s[i], chr)))
{
    combinations.Add(new Tuple<char, char>(s[i], chr));
}
                    
if(!combinations.Contains(Tuple<char, char> s[i], chr))
{
    combinations.Add(new Tuple<char, char>(s[i], chr));
}
```

Adding works fine so I thought it would be the same when comparing. Any help with syntax or logic would be great, thanks :)

Comment: You can use `.Contains(Tuple.Create(s[i], chr))`. Addition: If your `combinations` is a `List<Tuple<char, char>>` and you never want duplicates, maybe you want to use `HashSet<Tuple<char, char>>` instead? Its `Add` method will do nothing if the entry is already in the set.

Comment: I'm assuming you want to know if the tuple has the same values as one already in the list?  As opposed to actually being the same tuple (same memory address)?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Tuples already implement the appropriate equality, so you shouldn't need to do anything except create the value, and then use `.Contains`. However:

1. you may prefer `ValueTuple<...>` over `Tuple<...>`, and
2. if order doesn't matter, you may prefer `HashSet<T>`, which handles uniqueness internally

For example:

```
// note that (char, char) is a ValueTuple<char, char>
private readonly HashSet<(char,char)> combinations = new();
//...
combinations.Add((x, y)); // adds the x/y tuple if it doesn't exist
```

You can also *name* the parts here:

```cs
private readonly HashSet<(char X,char Y)> combinations = new();
```

which will allow you to use `.X` and `.Y` on values, via compiler voodoo.

Answer (score 4):

In C#, you can use the Contains() method to check if a list contains a specific tuple. Here is an example:

```
// List of tuples
var tupleList = new List<(char, char)>()
{
    ('a', 'b'),
    ('c', 'd'),
    ('e', 'f')
};

// Tuple to search for
var searchTuple = ('a', 'b');

// Check if the list contains the tuple
if (tupleList.Contains(searchTuple))
{
    Console.WriteLine("The list contains the tuple");
}
else
{
    Console.WriteLine("The list does not contain the tuple");
}
```